# How do i avoid overlapping when using column Listview.builder inside column in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout

I have this code which causes the bottom to overlap and I cannot figure out what to do. I use a listview.builder which has a column with another listview.builder inside.

image of overlap of text but the listtile continues

[image]

the code

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                (_deviceWidth! * 0.05), 10, (_deviceWidth! * 0.05), 0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _titleText(),
              
                ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _exercises.length,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int _index) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              if (_exercises[_index].sets.isNotEmpty)
                Text(_exercises[_index].name),
              ListView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: _exercises[_index].sets.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext _context, int _index2) {
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: Text("Sæt " + (_index2 + 1).toString()),
                      trailing: Text(
                          _exercises[_index].sets[_index2].reps.toString() +
                              " reps"),
                      tileColor: Colors.grey,
                      onTap: () {
                        _repsPopUp(_index, _index2);
                      },
                      title: Text(_exercises[_index].name),
                      onLongPress: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _exercises[_index].sets.removeAt(_index2);
                          if (_exercises[_index].sets.isEmpty) {
                            _exercises.removeAt(_index);
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  }),
            ],
          );
        });
                
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: failed to reproduce the issue, everything seems working on web test

Comment: Did you mean you don't know what did overlapping your text ?